# Getting this error RuntimeError: size mismatch, m1: [10 x 33], m2: [34 x 10]

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I am building a neural network to solve my classification problem, but for some reason Im getting the error RuntimeError: size mismatch, m1: [10 x 33], m2: [34 x 10]. I dont understand what im doing wrong.
Here is my code.

```
X_train= torch.tensor(X_train, dtype= torch.float)
X_test= torch.tensor(X_test, dtype= torch.float )
Y_train= torch.tensor(Y_train, dtype= torch.float).view(-1,1)
Y_test= torch.tensor(Y_test, dtype= torch.float).view(-1,1)

dataset= torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(X_train, Y_train)

train_iter = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=10, shuffle=True)
```

import torch.nn.functional as F

```
class Network(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Inputs to hidden layer linear transformation
        self.hidden = nn.Linear(34, 10)
        # Output layer, 10 units - one for each digit
        self.output = nn.Linear(10, 1)

        # Define sigmoid activation and softmax output 
        self.sigmoid_act = nn.Sigmoid()
        self.ReLU_act= nn.ReLU()

    def forward(self, x):
        # Pass the input tensor through each of our operations
        x = self.hidden(x)
        x = self.ReLU_act(x)
        x = self.output(x)
        x = self.sigmoid_act(x)

        return x

model= Network()
criterion = nn.BCELoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.003)

epochs = 30
steps = 0

train_losses, test_losses = [], []
for e in range(epochs):
    running_loss = 0
    for images, labels in train_iter:

        optimizer.zero_grad()

        **log_ps = model(images)**
        loss = criterion(log_ps, labels)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        running_loss += loss.item()

    else:
        test_loss = 0
        accuracy = 0
```

Im getting the error on the line in bold. Please help me resolve this. Im stuck on it for almost a day now. Im a beginner at neural networks.

Comment: Which line throws the error?